# Accessing Tuleap project via vps ip address instead of tuleap.example.com

Tags: tuleap

I have purchased a VPS(centos 6) and I installed tuleap in it. After I install the web application as per guidelines given here: http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html
it says that the project can be accessed using http://tuleap.example.com

But I didn't set up a domain name yet to my VPS IP address. I know that some changes need to be made either of the following. But I am not aware of the modifications. Please guide me so that I can access using just the IP address alone.

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
/etc/codendi/conf/local.inc

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open your port on the firewall.

If you are using Centos 6:

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo service iptables save
```

This link might help you:
http://ask.xmodulo.com/open-port-firewall-centos-rhel.html

Answer (score 1):

You should just have to put you ip adress instead of a domain name wherever it is required in the two files you indicated. Then `service httpd restart` and it should be working.

Comment: Sorry Martin, I tried a lot but couldn't find a way out. I visited your website shown in your profile but didn't see any ways to contact you. Can I have your email id?

Also, I would like to uninstall tuleap and install freshly. This time I would like to disable subdomains and give my ip address while installing tuleap itself. Can I know how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The easiest path is to format your vm and relaunch a Tuleap installation from a fresh centos6 vm. This time provide a domain name or at least put your ip adress as the domain name when requested.